# Replace characters in shell variable

Tags: bash, shell, sed, grep, tr

Hi I have a shell variable like this

```
input="/local/1/hadoop/MISDATA1/Risk_Analytics/blocker/risk/"
```

I want to replace the last part 'risk' to 'risk_unzip' like this

```
/local/1/hadoop/MISDATA1/Risk_Analytics/blocker/risk_unzip/
```

I tried like this

```
output="$( echo -e "$input" | tr 'risk' 'risk_unzip' )"
```

Not works for me. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: DO you want to replace the last directory in the path, or specifically the word risk wherever it occurs in the path, or something else? Is the replacement always "risk_unzip" or is it based on the value of the strings being replaced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `sed` like below:-

```
input="/local/1/hadoop/MISDATA1/Risk_Analytics/blocker/risk/"
input=$(echo "$input" | sed 's/risk/risk_unzip/g')
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using bash:

```
output=${input/risk/risk_input}
```

If you want it to work with any Posix shell (in which case, the bash tag is incorrect), but you know that `risk` is the last component:

```
output=${input%risk/}risk_input/
```

Answer (score 0):

Following may help you on same.

```
echo "$input" | awk -F"/" '$(NF-1)=="risk"{$(NF-1)="risk_unzip"} 1' OFS="/"
```